# Considering all the permutations of the following word, what is the total number of words in which the the following condition is true? ${}$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Among all the permutations of the letters of the word " JANLOKPAL", the number of words in which "O" never lies between "J" and "N" is?

I first thought of subtracting the cases in which O does occur between J and N, and then subtracting it from total possible permutations, but I can't seem to arrive at the correct answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Your argument is correct! Can you post the calculation you did, so we can check where the error is?

Comment: Never lies between J and N is rather vague. So if J is on the first position and N in the last, no permutations can work? Or do the J and N have to be exactly 2 apart?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I guess it is the second option. Furthermore, I think that J (and N as well) can be either be on the left or on the right of the O.

Comment: Hey , thank you @A.Pesare for the help !!!! I sent the question to one of my friends , and he sent this solution .please check if this is correct .

Comment: He put the O ,J and N at some random place , and supposed the gap left between these digits as X,y,z and w . The sum of X y z and w is always 6 , so it the number of possible solutions of X+y+z+w = 6 is equals 9C3 . Now this is the case where O is on the leftmost side , then J and then N . Multiplied it by 2 and again multiplied by total permutations of remains words in the gaps . Answer came out to be 6*7!.

Comment: For what its worth, in my opinion, although Inclusion-Exclusion is normally preferred over the direct approach, I question whether the direct approach would not be just as easy in this problem.  That is, assuming that $J$ precedes $N$, $J$ and $N$ are separated by $k$ slots, where $k \in \{0,1,\cdots, 7\}.$  Just as easy to enumerate number of ways that $O$ is between $J$ and $N$ as number of ways that $O$ is **not** between $J$ and $N$.

Comment: I take the question to mean that only $JON$ and $NOJ$ are forbidden

Answer (score 3):

**Interpretation 1: Only JON and NOJ are disallowed**

There are $9$ letters which include two doubles.

Unrestricted permutations $ = \dfrac{9!}{2!2!}= P\;say$

Now form $2$ **blocks**, $JON$ and $NOJ$ along with the remaining $6$ letters which have two doubles,

"bad" permutations = $2\times \frac{7!}{2!2!} = Q,\;say$

and "good" permutations = $P-Q = 88200$

---

**Interpretation 2: O can't be anywhere between J..N or N...J**

Unrestricted permutations $ = \dfrac{9!}{2!2!}= P\;say$

Put $JON/NOJ$ together and start inserting unlabelled letters one by one between interstices, *then* label them.(With each insertion, the number of interstices will rise by $1$), and  so "bad" words = $2\times\dfrac{4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9}{2!2!}= Q,\;say$,

Finally good words $=P-Q = 60480$

Comment: The way I read this question any permutation is admissible except those in which the O appears somewhere between the J and the N.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Actually, OP should clarify. Anyway, I have added another answer according to your interpretation, which could very well be what OP intended.

Comment: Your solution is pretty straightforward too!

Answer (score 3):

Let's count the words which contains blocks JON or NOJ. _J_O_N_ has four spaces around it and we have to put six more letters. One letter can be filled in four ways. Now our block looks like e.g., _J_O_A_N_. We have five spots available for second letter. We go on filling, as the available spots keeps increasing by $1$.

Number of words containing JON or NOJ (keeping in mind to not overcount the two repeated letters) is
$$2 \times \frac{4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9}{2!2!}$$

Subtracting this from total, desired result is
$$\frac{9!}{2!2!}-\frac{9!}{2!2!\times 3}=\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{9!}{2!2!}=60480$$

---

Looking at the last expression, we realize that we could have simply ignored other letters. Since from $3!$ permutations of $J,O,N$, only four were desired, the straightforward answer is
$$\frac{4}{3!}\times\frac{9!}{2!2!}=\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{9!}{2!2!}=60480$$

Comment: For the last part (+1). In the hustle and bustle, mind tends to go into familiar grooves !

Comment: My Addendum-2 crossbred the end of your answer with Stars and Bars.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, my answer, $60480 = 2 \times 6 \times 7!$ 
I strongly suspect that there is a more elegant approach.
Anyway...

See the Addendum, for an embarassingly elegant Stars and Bars approach, that I just thought of.

---

First, see my comment, following the OP's query.  I am going to

- use the direct approach
- assume that $J$ precedes $N$, obtain the count, and then multiply it by $2$.
- assume that the number of letters between $J$ and $N$ is $k$, where $k \in \{0,1,\cdots, 7\}$.
- let $f(k)$ denote the number of ways that $O$ does not lie between $J$ and $N$, as a function of $k$.

Then the answer will be $2 \times \left[\sum_{k=0}^7 f(k)\right].$

It should be noted that if there was no constraint on where $O$ occurred, the number of 9 character sequences would be

$$\frac{9!}{2! \times 2!}.$$

This is because there are 2 $A$'s and 2 $L$'s in the sequence, and the enumeration of $9!$ **double-counts** each specific positioning of the 2 $A$'s and (separately) each specific positioning of the 2 $L$'s.

$\underline{f(0)}$
There are $8$ choices for where the $J$ occurs, with the $N$ immediately following it.  For each of these choices, since it is impossible for the $O$ to be between the $J$ and the $N$, there are $\frac{7!}{2! \times 2!}$ ways.

Therefore, 
$\displaystyle f(0) = 8 \times \frac{7!}{2! \times 2!}.$

$\underline{f(1)}$
There are $7$ choices for where the $J$ occurs, with the $N$ separated from the $J$ by one slot.  Here, for convenience, I will internally use Inclusion-Exclusion, within this individual case.

For each of these $7$ choices:

- There are $\frac{7!}{2! \times 2!}$ ways of forming a word, with the $J$ and $N$ so positioned.
- Of these, the only way of violating the constraint is if $O$ is in the single slot in between the $J$ and the $N$.  This can happen in $\frac{6!}{2! \times 2!}$ ways.

Therefore, 
$\displaystyle f(1) = 7 \times \frac{7! - 6!}{2! \times 2!}.$

---

The remainder of the analysis will be very similar to the analysis in computing $f(1)$.

---

$\underline{f(2)}$
There are $6$ choices for $J$**$N$

For each of these $6$ choices:

- There are $\frac{7!}{2! \times 2!}$ ways of forming a word, with the $J$ and $N$ so positioned.
- To violate the constraint, there are $2$ slots, that the $O$ can appear in.  For each of these slots, a **dis-satisfying** word can be formed in
  $\frac{6!}{2! \times 2!}$ ways.

Therefore, 
$\displaystyle f(2) = 6 \times \frac{7! - (2 \times 6!)}{2! \times 2!}.$

$\underline{f(3)}$
There are $5$ choices for $J$***$N$.

For each of these $5$ choices:

- there are $\frac{7!}{2! \times 2!}$ ways of forming a word.
- To violate the constraint, there are $3$ slots, that the $O$ can appear in.  For each of these slots, a **dis-satisfying** word can be formed in $\frac{6!}{2! \times 2!}$ ways.

Therefore, 
$\displaystyle f(3) = 5 \times \frac{7! - (3 \times 6!)}{2! \times 2!}.$

The pattern is clear.

$\displaystyle f(4) = 4 \times \frac{7! - (4 \times 6!)}{2! \times 2!}.$

$\displaystyle f(5) = 3 \times \frac{7! - (5 \times 6!)}{2! \times 2!}.$

$\displaystyle f(6) = 2 \times \frac{7! - (6 \times 6!)}{2! \times 2!}.$

$\displaystyle f(7) = 1 \times \frac{7! - (7 \times 6!)}{2! \times 2!}.$

As expected, $f(7) = 0$.

The summation can be facilitated by simplifying each expression for $f(k)$, noting that $\frac{1}{2! \times 2!} = \frac{1}{4},$ and noting that $(7!) = (7 \times 6!)$.

$$f(k) = \frac{1}{4} \times (8 - k) \times (7 - k) \times 6!.$$

Note that

$$\sum_{k=0}^7 (8-k) \times (7-k) = 56 + 42 + 30 + 20 + 12 + 6 + 2 + 0 = 168.$$

Thus,

$$2 \times \left[\sum_{k=0}^7 f(k)\right]$$

$$ =~ 2 \times \frac{6!}{4} \left[\sum_{k=0}^7 (8-k)(7-k)
\right]$$

$$ =~2 \times 180 \times 168 = 60480.$$

---

If I had opted for the alternative (indirect) approach of employing Inclusion-Exclusion, from the start, my work would have been equally inelegant.  Others might have found a more elegant use of Inclusion-Exclusion here.

---

**Addendum** 
Use [Stars and Bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/).

The scaling factor of $\frac{1}{2! \times 2!} = \frac{1}{4}$ will pertain, throughout the Addendum.  I will therefore omit it, until the final computation.

There are $9!$ ways of forming any 9 character string.

Consider the letters JON as bars, occurring in that specific order, placed as

$$ \text{*}J\text{*}O\text{*}N\text{*}$$

To enumerate the number of **bad** words that can be created, you first have to enumerate the number of solutions to

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 6 ~~ \text{number of solutions equals}~~ \binom{6 + [4-1]}{4-1} = 84.$$

For each such solution, the remaining $6$ letters can be placed in $(6!)$ ways.

Further, by symmetry, you have to multiply this computation by $2$ to account for the
$ \text{*}N\text{*}O\text{*}J\text{*}$ words.

Therefore, the **final computation** is

$$\frac{1}{2! \times 2!} \times 
\left[(9!) ~-~ 2 \times 84 \times 6!\right] = 60480.$$

---

**Addendum-2**
Hijacking the analysis at the end of cosmo5's answer, and transplanting it into the Stars and Bars flowerbed:

Consider:

$$ \text{*}O\text{*}J\text{*}N\text{*}$$

There are actually 4 such sequences, re
$OJN, ONJ, JNO, NJO$.

Therefore, for the direct approach, you would have

$$\frac{1}{2! \times 2!} \times 4 \times 84 \times 6! = 60480.$$

Comment: I like your second approach.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation is same as what N.F. Taussig said that all are permissible arrangements except where $O$ is somewhere between $J$ and $N$.

Here is how I counted -

Total permissible arrangements $ = \displaystyle \frac{9!}{2! \ 2!}$

We first make all bad arrangements. So we start with placing $ \_ J \_ O \_ N \_ $ . That gives us $4$ spaces and we either choose one of the places to place two $L$ together or we choose two of $4$ places for one L each. Now we have a string of $5$ letters and that gives us $6$ spaces. We now place two $A$ the same way. Then we have a string of $7$ letters and we place $K$ in one of the $8$ places and finally $P$ in one of the $9$ places.

We have same number of arrangements for $N \ O \ J$.

Lastly, we subtract from total arrangements to find number of good arrangements.

So the answer is

$\displaystyle \small \frac{9!}{2! \ 2!} - 2 \cdot \bigg[{4 \choose 1} + {4 \choose 2}\bigg] \cdot \bigg[{6 \choose 1} + {6 \choose 2}\bigg] \cdot 8 \cdot 9 = 60480$

Answer (score 1):

We can count directly.

The word JANLOKPAL contains nine letters, of which one is a J, two are As, one is an N, two are Ls, one is an O, and one is a K.  We wish to count those permutations of the letters of the word JANLOKPAL in which the O does not appear somewhere between the J and the N.

We have nine positions to fill.  Choose two of the nine positions for the As, two of the remaining seven positions for the Ls, one of the remaining five positions for the K, one of of the remaining four positions for the P.  That leaves three positions to fill with J, N, and O.  Since the O cannot be placed between the J and the N, it must fill either the first or last of these positions, giving us two choices for placing the O.  Once we have placed the O, there are no further restrictions.  Hence, we can place the J and N in the remaining two positions in $2!$ ways.  Thus, there are
$$\binom{9}{2}\binom{7}{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 2 \cdot 2! = 60,480$$
permutations of the letters of the word JANLOKPAL in which the O does not appear somewhere between the J and the N.